# mdt: command not found [mendel development tool]

Tags: google-coral

I've flashed my Google Coral Dev Board going through the instructions on this page:
https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/dev-board/get-started/#requirements

I've downloaded the mendel development tool with

```
    pip3 install --user mendel-development-tool
```

But when I try to connect to the board's shell via MDT, using

```
    mdt shell
```

I'm met with

```
    mdt: command not found
```

I'm using a macOS, for reference. Any advice on whether I've downloaded MDT correctly, or am missing something else is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened because your command `mdt`is not in your terminal PATH.

The solution is to add the path to PATH. You can check if the **/Users/username/Library/Python/3.7/bin** is in your shell path by running the command (**username** would be your username):

`echo $PATH`

If not, open `~/.bash` or `~./bash_profile` (For bash. If you are using zsh, then it would be `~/.zshrc`.) with editor (vim or vi) by running:

`vim ~/.bash` or `vim ~/.bash_profile`

and add the path `/Users/username/Library/Python/3.7/bin` (replace **username** to your own username)to the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I found the mdt tool is located at: ~/Library/Python/3.7/bin. So I add this path to PATH.

Comment: yelp, add 
`export PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Python/3.7/bin`
to your .bashrc

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about macOS architecture but I had the same problem and nothing worked for me as those solutions were outdated. My macOS is running on Monterey 12.0.1 and here are my steps:

1. Examine whether you are a `shell` or `zsh` user. ([How to check terminal type](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93376/which-terminal-type-am-i-using))
2. Run the command `python3 -m pip install --user mendel-development-tool`
3. Run based on your terminal type (shell or zsh):
   `echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile`
   OR (NOT BOTH)
   `echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"' >> ~/.zshrc`

**Final note:** You might need to update zsh if you are using it. If you are a shell user, you might want to consider upgrading to zsh.

Run `brew update` to update brew

Run `brew install zsh` to install/update zsh

Run `sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"` to install/update Oh My Zsh